# Handle SAML POST and still maintaining CSRF in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, saml-2.0

I use this package = https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2
I configured everything in the SP and iDP sections in **saml2_settings.php** as instructed.

---

## STEPS

I go to : `/admin/login`
I got redirected and landed on my iDP log-in page immediately, it is a correct behavior.

I log-in with the proper username and password.

[image]

After successfully authenticated by my iDP, I got the SAML Response from my iDP like this sample

```
{
"SAMLResponse": "PHNhbWxwOlJlc3BvbnNlIHhtbG5zOnNhbWxwPSJ1cm46b2FzaXM6bmFtZXM6dGM6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\r\nUmVzcG9uc2U+\r\n",
"RelayState": "https://testserver.benunets.com/admin/login"
}
```

---

## kernel.php

I can only see this response only because I comment out my CFRF token on my `app/Http/kernel.php`

```
// \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

---

## ROUTE

```
Route::post('admin/secure/dashboard', 'SAMLController@post');
```

## CONTROLLER

```
 public function post(){
    return Input::all();
}
```

---

What is the best practice to deal with SAML POST and still maintaining CSRF protection ?

Should I create a middleware or anything similar to that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may exclude your endpoint by adding it to the `$except` property of the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware.

After that you may want to add your own middleware to check if the post request came from an origin you explicitly accept.

The documentation of the package also states that you should configure a middleware group in te config which at least needs the `StartSession` middleware. So you can make a special middleware-group which excludes the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware. However, I do believe it would be better to exclude the endpoint, and add your own middleware check.

Also, you are referencing the url `admin/secure/dashboard`. Are you using this for debugging the POST request? Because I believe the actual endpoint for iDP needs to be `https://your-url.com/saml2/acs` (unless you changed the default configuration). This page will use the post data to trigger an event with which you can login the appropriate user.

Comment: I don't know what to use the `https://your-url.com/saml2/acs` for, but I will look into it.

Comment: My `admin/secure/dashboard` is the dashboard link/page that I should redirect user to after successfully authenticated. Please kindly advise, I am very new on this whole SAML implementation.

Comment: If you have set `'useRoutes' => true` and `assertionConsumerService` still empty, then you should be redirected the user to `saml2/acs` (after authentication). That will in turn read the post request via `OneLogin_Saml2_Auth` and create a `$user` object for you. It also fires off the `Saml2LoginEvent` containing that user-object. After that it will redirect you to a page given bij OneLogin, or what you've entered in the config file under `'loginRoute' => '/'`. I think your `admin/secure/dashboard` should go there. Also read the comments in `saml2_settings.php`. It explains a lot.